# wxpython TextCtrlAutoComplete widget crushes after destroy (events issue)

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm modifying the wxpython app with TextCtrlAutoComplete widget on some panel. There is a bug after I destroy the panel which contain the TextCtrlAutoComplete widget. It seems that after destoying there are still some events active (in particular EVT_MOVE, EVT_SIZE) which links to TextCtrlAutoComplete.onControlChanged method. This causes dead object error. So, my question is is there any way to clean up all of the events which are linked to particular object methods. Right now TextCtrlAutoComplete binds the events to self and all of the parents above:

```
    gp = self
    while ( gp != None ) :
        gp.Bind ( wx.EVT_MOVE , self.onControlChanged, gp )
        gp.Bind ( wx.EVT_SIZE , self.onControlChanged, gp )
        gp = gp.GetParent()
```

The issue is that after Destroy() is called those events are still active!

Below is very simple app which demonstrated the bug.

```
import wx
from wxext.TextCtrlAutoComplete import TextCtrlAutoComplete

########################################################################
class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.txt = wx.StaticText(self, label="Panel One")
        self.txt.SetFont(wx.Font(14,wx.DEFAULT,wx.NORMAL,wx.BOLD))
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Button1', pos=(8, 8), size=(175, 28))
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton1Click)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.txt, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=20)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button1, 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, border=20)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def onButton1Click(self,event):
        if (self.GetParent().panelTwo):
            self.SetBackgroundColour("lightblue")
            self.GetParent().panelTwo.Destroy()
            self.txt.SetLabel("Move of Size event lead to BUG")
            self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        else:
            self.SetBackgroundColour("lightgrey")

########################################################################
class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("darkgreen")
        self.txt = wx.StaticText(self, label="Panel Two")
        self.txt.SetFont(wx.Font(14,wx.DEFAULT,wx.NORMAL,wx.BOLD))
        self.searchbox = TextCtrlAutoComplete(self, choices=['No parameter found'])
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.txt, 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, border=20)
        self.sizer.Add(self.searchbox, 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, border=20)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)



########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Bug")
        self.panelOne = PanelOne(self)
        self.panelTwo = PanelTwo(self)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panelOne, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panelTwo, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I cannot seem to import `wxext.TextCtrlAutoComplete`. I think this is written incorrectly. I also cannot find any widget called `TextCtrlAutoComplete` in the wxPython documentation. Are you using the AutoComplete method of the TextEntry widget perhaps? Which version of wxPython are you using and which OS?

Comment: I'm using TextCtrlAutoComplete.py from wxex collection. Here is the example of the code (https://code.google.com/p/malodos/source/browse/tags/1.2.1/src/gui/TextCtrlAutoComplete.py?r=188)

Comment: Here is wiki for this class: wiki.wxpython.org/TextCtrlAutoComplete

Comment: Is the dead object exception in the event handlers 'onControlChanged'?

Comment: Yes, above is the place in code which causes the error. It seems like the binding EVT_MOVE/SIZE up to the main frame breaks the dependency inversion  principle.